# Find the substring avoiding the use of recursive function

Tags: python, algorithm, recursion, math, big-o

I am studying algorithms in Python and solving a question that is:

> Let x(k) be a recursively defined string with base case x(1) = "123"
> and   x(k) is "1" + x(k-1) + "2" + x(k-1) + "3". Given three positive
> integers k,s, and t, find the substring x(k)[s:t].
>
> For example, if k = 2, s = 1 and t = 5,x(2) = 112321233 and x(2)[1:5]
> = 1232.

I have solved it using a simple recursive function:

```py
   def generate_string(k):
        if k == 1:
            return "123"
            
        part = generate_string(k -1)
        return ("1" + part  + "2" + part + "3")
        print(generate_string(k)[s,t])
```

Although my first approach gives correct answer, the problem is that it takes too long to build string x when k is greater than 20. The program need to be finished within 16 seconds while k is below 50. I have tried to use memoization but it does not help as I am not allowed to cache each test case. I thus think that I must avoid using recursive function to speed up the program. Is there any approaches I should consider?

Comment: Case k=20 is doing in 3ms for me, but just before 30 it goes to Memory error, I don't think you can achieve tht

Comment: The length if the result sting is given by `((2 ** k) - 1) * 3`, for 20 you're at 3millions len, for 40 you're at 3 trillions length, for 50 at 1600 trillions, you can't achieve that ;)

Comment: What is the maximum size of `t-s` ?

Comment: Dear Damien, it is 100.

Comment: A recursive function is a good idea, but generate the needed characters only, using the knowledge of the size of string `k-1`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We can see that the string represented by `x(k)`  grows exponentially in length with increasing *k*:

```
len(x(1)) == 3
len(x(k)) == len(x(k-1)) * 2 + 3
```

So:

```
len(x(k)) == 3 * (2**k - 1)
```

For *k* equal to 100, this amounts to a length of more than 10<sup>30</sup>. That's more characters than there are atoms in a human body!

Since the parameters *s* and *t* will take (in comparison) a tiny, tiny slice of that, you should not need to produce the whole string. You can still use recursion though, but keep passing an *s* and *t* range to each call. Then when you see that this slice will actually be *outside* of the string you would generate, then you can just exit without recursing deeper, saving a **lot** of time and (string) space.

Here is how you could do it:

```
def getslice(k, s, t):
    def recur(xsize, s, t):
        if xsize == 0 or s >= xsize or t <= 0:
            return ""
        smaller = (xsize - 3) // 2
        return ( ("1" if s <= 0 else "")
               + recur(smaller, s-1, t-1)
               + ("2" if s <= smaller+1 < t else "")
               + recur(smaller, s-smaller-2, t-smaller-2)
               + ("3" if t >= xsize else "") )
    return recur(3 * (2**k - 1), s, t)
```

This doesn't use any caching of `x(k)` results... In my tests this was fast enough.

Comment: Upvoted, but OP explicitly asked for "avoiding the use of recursive function" in the question title. (I added an iterative answer.)

Comment: Indeed, but the OP feels recursion was responsible for their timeout problems. It is not.

Comment: This is a very good answer indeed – much better than the idea I initially sketched out.

Comment: This is incredibly fast recursive solution which I could not think of. I really appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1):

This is an interesting problem. I'm not sure whether I'll have time to write the code, but here's an outline of how you can solve it. **Note**: see the better answer from [trincot](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62490914/55857).

As discussed in the comments, you cannot generate the actual string: you will quickly run out of memory as `k` grows. But you can easily compute the length of that string.

First some notation:

```
f(k) : The generated string.
n(k) : The length of f(k).
nk1  : n(k-1), which is used several times in table below.
```

For discussion purposes, we can divide the string into the following regions. The start/end values use standard Python slice numbering:

```
Region | Start         | End           | Len | Subtring | Ex: k = 2
-------------------------------------------------------------------
A      | 0             | 1             | 1   | 1        | 0:1  1
B      | 1             | 1 + nk1       | nk1 | f(k-1)   | 1:4  123
C      | 1 + nk1       | 2 + nk1       | 1   | 2        | 4:5  2
D      | 2 + nk1       | 2 + nk1 + nk1 | nk1 | f(k-1)   | 5:8  123
E      | 2 + nk1 + nk1 | 3 + nk1 + nk1 | 1   | 3        | 8:9  3
```

Given `k`, `s`, and `t` we need to figure out which region of the string is relevant. Take a small example:

```
k=2, s=6, and t=8.

The substring defined by 6:8 does not require the full f(k). We only need
region D, so we can turn our attention to f(k-1).

To make the shift from k=2 to k=1, we need to adjust s and t: specifically,
we need to subtract the total length of regions A + B + C. For k=2, that
length is 5 (1 + nk1 + 1).

Now we are dealing with: k=1, s=1, and t=3.

Repeat as needed.
```

Whenever k gets small enough, we stop this nonsense and actually generate the string so we can grab the needed substring directly.

It's possible that some values of `s` and `t` could cross region boundaries. In that case, divide the problem into two subparts (one for each region needed). But the general idea is the same.

Answer (score 1):

Based on [@FMc's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62489475/6553328), here's some python3 code that calculates `x(k, s, t)`:

```
from functools import lru_cache
from typing import *


def f_len(k) -> int:
    return 3 * ((2 ** k) - 1)


@lru_cache(None)
def f(k) -> str:
    if k == 1:
        return "123"
    return "1" + f(k - 1) + "2" + f(k - 1) + "3"


def substring_(k, s, t, output) -> None:
    # Empty substring.
    if s >= t or k == 0:
        return

    # (An optimization):
    # If all the characters need to be included, just calculate the string and cache it.
    if s == 0 and t == f_len(k):
        output.append(f(k))
        return

    if s == 0:
        output.append("1")

    sub_len = f_len(k - 1)
    substring_(k - 1, max(0, s - 1), min(sub_len, t - 1), output)

    if s <= 1 + sub_len < t:
        output.append("2")

    substring_(k - 1, max(0, s - sub_len - 2), min(sub_len, t - sub_len - 2), output)

    if s <= 2 * (1 + sub_len) < t:
        output.append("3")


def substring(k, s, t) -> str:
    output: List[str] = []
    substring_(k, s, t, output)
    return "".join(output)


def test(k, s, t) -> bool:
    actual = substring(k, s, t)
    expected = f(k)[s:t]
    return actual == expected


assert test(1, 0, 3)
assert test(2, 2, 6)
assert test(2, 1, 5)
assert test(2, 0, f_len(2))
assert test(3, 0, f_len(3))
assert test(8, 44, 89)
assert test(10, 1001, 2022)
assert test(14, 12345, 45678)
assert test(17, 12345, 112345)
# print(substring(30, 10000, 10100))
print("Tests passed")
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a commented iterative version in JavaScript that's very easy to convert to Python.

In addition to being what you asked for, that is non-recursive, it allows us to solve things like `f(10000, 10000, 10050)`, which seem to exceed Python default recursion depth.

```js
// Generates the full string
function g(k){
  if (k == 1)
    return "123";
  prev = g(k - 1);
  return "1" + prev + "2" + prev + "3";
}

function size(k){
  return 3 * ((1 << k) - 1);
}

// Given a depth and index,
// we'd like (1) a string to
// output, (2) the possible next
// part of the same depth to
// push to the stack, and (3)
// possibly the current section
// mapped deeper to also push to
// the stack. (2) and (3) can be
// in a single list.
function getParams(depth, i){
  const psize = size(depth - 1);

  if (i == 0){
    return ["1", [[depth, 1 + psize], [depth - 1, 0]]];
    
  } else if (i < 1 + psize){
    return ["", [[depth, 1 + psize], [depth - 1, i - 1]]];
    
  } else if (i == 1 + psize){
    return ["2", [[depth, 2 + 2 * psize], [depth - 1, 0]]];
    
  } else if (i < 2 + 2 * psize){
    return ["", [[depth, 2 + 2 * psize], [depth - 1, i - 2 - psize]]];
    
  } else {
    return ["3", []];
  }
}

function f(k, s, t){
  let len = t - s;
  let str = "";
  let stack = [[k, s]];
  
  while (str.length < len){
    const [depth, i] = stack.pop();

    if (depth == 1){
      const toTake = Math.min(3 - i, len - str.length);
      str = str + "123".substr(i, toTake);
      
    } else {
      const [s, rest] = getParams(depth, i);
      str = str + s;
      stack.push(...rest);
    }
  }
  
  return str;
}

function test(k, s, t){
  const l = g(k).substring(s, t);
  const r = f(k, s, t);
  console.log(g(k).length);
  //console.log(g(k))
  console.log(l);
  console.log(r);
  console.log(l == r);
}

test(1, 0, 3);
test(2, 2, 6);
test(2, 1, 5);
test(4, 44, 45);
test(5, 30, 40);
test(7, 100, 150);
```